# Is it possible to change a weight matrix $W$ so it minimize a vector $J$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, parameter-estimation, gradient-descent

Assume that we have a weight matrix $W \in \Re^{n x n}$ somewhere and if it's changing, then a vector $J \in \Re^{m}$ is going to be minimized.

The problem is that this is not an ordinary optimization problem such as

$$J = W^Tx$$

Or

$$J = x^TWx$$

It's more like a big model where somewhere inside the model, there are a "tuning parameter", called the weight matrix $W$ and it's affecting the output $J$.

I don't know if it's possible to find a way to optimize $W$ with respect on $J$.

**Question:**

If you had an algorithm that contains a weight matrix $W$ and it's affecting the output vector $J$. When the sum of $J$ is small, then $W$ and all other parameters are optimal. But how can this be done? Assume that all othe parameters are constants and only $W$ can be changed to minimize the sum of $J$ vector.

How can that be done?